# Running bundle install fails trying to remote fetch from rubygems.org/quick/Marshal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm getting a strange error when doing bundle install:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:304
    :in `open_uri_or_path': bad response Not Found 404 
    (http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/resque-scheduler-1.09.7.gemspec.rz) 
    (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
```

I've tried bundle update, gem source -c, gem update --system, gem cleanup, etc etc.
Nothing seems to solve this.
I notice that the URL beginning with http://rubygems.org/quick does seem to be a 404 -- I don't think that's any problem with my network, though if that's reachable for anyone else then that would be a simple explanation for my problem.

More hints:  If I just gem install resque-scheduler it works fine:

```
$ gem install resque-scheduler
Successfully installed resque-scheduler-1.9.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for resque-scheduler-1.9.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for resque-scheduler-1.9.7...
```

And here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'json'
gem 'rails', '>=3.0.0'
gem 'mongo'
gem 'mongo_mapper', :git => 'git://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper', :branch => 'rails3'
gem 'bson_ext', '1.1'
gem 'bson', '1.1'
gem 'mm-multi-parameter-attributes', :git=>'git://github.com/rlivsey/mm-multi-parameter-attributes.git'
gem 'devise', '~>1.1.3'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 0.3.4'
gem 'devise-mongo_mapper', :git => 'git://github.com/collectiveidea/devise-mongo_mapper'
gem 'carrierwave', :git => 'git://github.com/rsofaer/carrierwave.git' , :branch => 'master'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 0.2.6'
gem 'resque'
gem 'resque-scheduler'
gem 'SystemTimer'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
gem 'twitter', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'oauth', '~> 0.4.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not even a version of that gem available:

http://rubygems.org/gems/resque-scheduler/versions

Can you paste your Gemfile?

Also, that is supposed to be a 404, it's not a valid endpoint. That file is a compressed version of that gem's gemspec, which now lives on S3/CloudFront. Long story short, it's just where RubyGems wants things to live but we redirect out to a CDN now.

No idea why Bundler is requesting it though.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this!  I pasted in my Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing similar happening for other gems today. I suspect it's a rubygems.org issue.

Have you tried `sudo gem install resque-scheduler` - bundler should then use the local system gem once you have it installed.

I just did that and got version 1.9.7, not version 1.09.7 - you don't have a stray zero do you?

Comment: I can gem install resque-scheduler fine but then bundle install still fails the same way afterwards.

Comment: Nonsense use of sudo coz its being installed using the sweet RVM

Comment: Fair enough - copy paste because my system only lets me install gems with sudo. Who knows why?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have worked for me:

1. Comment out `gem 'resque-scheduler'` from Gemfile.
2. Run `bundle install`.
3. Uncomment `gem 'resque-scheduler'` in Gemfile.
4. Run `bundle install` again.

I have no idea why that worked and it's possible it was some other random flailing around I did like trying gem install bundler.  But right before trying the above 4 steps it was still failing the same way and right afterwards it worked.